# Are there any Euclidean Rings with a norm which is not additive nor multiplicative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, euclidean-domain

We note that a Euclidean Domain is an integral domain $R$ together with a norm function $N:R\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ such that for $a,b\in R$ with $b\neq 0$, there exists $q,r\in R$ such that $a=bq+r$ where $r=0$ or $N(r)<N(b)$. Furthermore, let us call the norm multiplicative if $N(ab)=N(a)N(b)$ and additive if $N(ab)=N(a)+N(b)$. I feel like most examples of Euclidean rings that I know of have either a multiplicative or additive norm. For example, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has a multiplicative norm, or $K[x]$ where $K$ is a field has an additive norm. However, I don't think I know of any examples of Euclidean Rings which have a norm that is not additive nor multiplicative. I was curious if there are any easy or natural examples, or if every (one that we care about) has a multiplicative or additive norm.

Comment: You can turn any additive norm into a multiplicative norm by defining $N'(x) = 2^{N(x)}$ (or any other integral base).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something simple, if $N$ is a norm on $R$ and $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is any strictly increasing function, then $f \circ N$ should also be a norm. Of course it's easy to cook up $f$ to guarantee that $f \circ N$ is not additive or multiplicative. So I guess the question is whether there are euclidean domains which _don't admit any_ multiplicative norms.

Comment: According to the above question, we know the answer is "yes, such rings exist", but this was open until quite recently!